# "Creating a routing tables" assignment

Tags: routing-table

I have to create "minimal routing tables that will provide proper connection in network". Additionally, I can assume, that both PCs have interface "eth0".

https://zapodaj.net/images/ecb738988990f.jpg

```
Router:
    adress          gateway     interface
    10.0.0.0        10.0.0.1    e1/1/1
    10.0.1.0        10.0.1.1    e1/1/2

Computer A:
    adress          gateway     interface
    0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1    eth0
    10.0.0.0        ???         eth0

Computer B:
    adress          gateway     interface
    0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1    eth0
    10.0.1.0        ???         eth0
```

Is this correct? And what address should I put in place of "???"

Comment: A routing table needs to have masks on the destination addresses. Also, routers don't _have_ gateways, they _are_ gateways, but they may have next hops, or next interface to use.

Comment: Huh? "Next hop" _is_ a gateway. In routing tables it's just two terms for the same thing.

Comment: @grawity, not necessarily. There are instances where that isn't the case. Also, you could have a next interface instead of a hop.

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't really a homework site, your attempt is close but not quite right.

1. Your "address" column lacks prefix lengths (or subnet masks). In your picture both networks are /24's, so that's what network routes should have as well. (Surely you're not basing this on pre-1983 classful routing?) Likewise, the "default" route would be 0.0.0.0/0 as it needs to match everything.
2. In the router's table, you have listed the router itself as the gateway/nexthop to reach both networks. That doesn't make any sense as it'd just result in an infinite loop.

   Since those networks are *on-link* (directly available on the corresponding interfaces), you don't need a gateway address there. Both rows would be direct interface routes. (Some operating systems may show "0.0.0.0" to indicate an empty gateway field, but it's still empty.)
3. The same applies to hosts as well. Since they're directly attached to that network, they have a direct route as well – there is no gateway address.

   (If they had to go through a gateway to reach their *own* subnet... How would they access the gateway itself?)

Answer (score 2):

```
Router:
    address         subnet         gateway      interface
    10.0.0.0        255.255.255.0  on-link      e1/1/1
    10.0.1.0        255.255.255.0  on-link      e1/1/2

Computer A:
    address         subnet         gateway      interface
    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0        10.0.0.1     eth0
    10.0.0.0        255.255.255.0  on-link      eth0

Computer B:
    address         subnet         gateway      interface
    0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0        10.0.1.1     eth0
    10.0.1.0        255.255.255.0  on-link      eth0
```

The router doesn't need gateways because all networks are directly connected to it. The computers don't need a gateway for directly connected subnets (eg. `10.100.0.0/24` for Computer A), because they don't need a gateway to reach computers on that subnet. They can just to a L2 ARP discovery to find hosts.

You do need a subnet mask in your routing table, because otherwise the router/computers won't be able to differentiate between the network and host part of the IP address.